# How to make Rails email templates to be editable from admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Im using rails 5 and active_admin and to manage application.

I want email templates which are in `/app/views/mailer_name` to be editable from admin section (in a way of html or CKEditor for example)

Are there any better (rubyist) ways rather than creating an database model and using global variables `$` ?